# mysql syntax error while using select query

Tags: c#, mysql, select, datetimepicker

I am getting this error when im using this command

```
MySqlCommand cmdDataBase = new MySqlCommand("select * from employee.transaction where department = '" + this.department.Text + "', month = '" + this.dateTimePicker1.Value.Month.ToString() + "' and year = '" + this.dateTimePicker1.Value.Year.ToString() + "' ;", conDataBase);
```

error :- you have an error in your sql syntax;check the manual that corresponds to your mysql server version for the right syntax to use near ' month = '7' and year = '2015" at line 1

month and year are of type Int in my table in mysql(version 5.6.25)

Can anyone help ?

Comment: `, month =` did you mean `and month =` ?

Comment: Thanks for the answers . Only needed "and" instead of "," and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use comma between your filters in your `WHERE` clause.

I think you try to write as `AND month...` instead of `, month...`

But more important, you should always use [parameterized queries.](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/) This kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

```
using(var conDataBase = MySqlConnection(conString))
using(var cmdDataBase = conDataBase.CreateCommand())
{
   cmdDatabase.CommandText = @"select * from employee.transaction 
                               where department = @department AND month = @month AND year = @year";
   cmdDatabase.Parameters.AddWithValue("@department", this.department.Text);
   cmdDatabase.Parameters.AddWithValue("@month", this.dateTimePicker1.Value.Month.ToString());
   cmdDatabase.Parameters.AddWithValue("@year", this.dateTimePicker1.Value.Year.ToString());
   // Do your work here
}
```

Also based on your column names, I *strongly* suspect your `month` and `year` columns should be numeric type, not character typed.

Comment: Now its not giving error but its not showing any data in the data grid view(its showing just a blank table)

Comment: how to use int value in the above query ? i.e what changes would have to be done in this :-                                                                                                     month = ' " + this.dateTimePicker1.Value.Month.ToString() + " '

Comment: @KaviKavi If you set your column types to integer, you can use `this.dateTimePicker1.Value.Month` and `this.dateTimePicker1.Value.Year` instead of their string representations.

Answer (score -1):

try this,
MySqlCommand cmdDataBase = new MySqlCommand("select * from employee.transaction where department = '" + this.department.Text + "' and month = '" + this.dateTimePicker1.Value.Month.ToString() + "' and year = '" + this.dateTimePicker1.Value.Year.ToString() + "'", conDataBase);